# Ldap and Bind are not working properly

Tags: php

i have made one small program in PHP which checks whether the user name and password are correct or not. I am getting "LDAP bind successful..." whenever i am putting the correct password but once i will change the password in Active directory and immediately put either new or old password, i am getting "LDAP bind successful..." message. I am not able to understand why i am getting "LDAP bind successful..." message when i am put the old password as it should be giving me an error. Following is my code. What i am missing here? How can i modify my code so that even after changing the password i will get the correct reply. Please note that I am new in PHP programming.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
$ldaprdn  = $_POST['name'];     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = $_POST['password']; // associated password

// connect to ldap servers
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://server")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");


    // binding to ldap server
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);

   if($ldapbind){
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
       $errno = ldap_errno( $ldapconn );
       echo $errno;
    }



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have `anonymous binding` enabled on your directory.

I would think that trying to bind with a name and password wouldn't fall back to anonymous binding, however, so there may be something else the matter.

I notice you are getting the bind name/pass from `$_POST` (unsanitized BTW, tisk tisk) so perhaps your form is not actually set up for post data (leading to blank values), or your field name is incorrect. I know if `$ldaprdn == ""` then it will bind anonymously so check that value to make sure it is something useful.

I see you are using Active Directory so perhapps you would find [this `adldap` library](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/) more useful

Comment: Thank you for you reply... I am getting error when i put the wrong password. I am getting "LDAP bind is successful..." message only when i enter old password or the new password. I have checked my code with anonymous binding and its working fine.

Comment: For example if you will enter the correct user name and password for example (user:stackoverflow and password:1234) then you will get the "LDAP bind is successful". Now after getting successful message, if you will enter the wrong password (user:stackoverflow and password:1235) you will get the error. Till here my code is working fine. If you will change the password of stackoverflow user id for example the new password is now (new password: 0987) in Active directory and again if you will run the program and enter (user:stackoverflow and password:1234) you will get "LDAP bind is successful"

Comment: @user1577864 I would still validate the actual values of both `$ldaprdn` and `$ldappass` are you using any non-ASCII characters in user or password?

Comment: I just echo $ldaprdn and $ldappass. I am getting the correct user name and password. I am using $,% in my test passwords but also i tried simple passwords as well like combinations of capital, small letters and numbers.

Comment: @user1577864 do you get the same result when using `adLDAP`?